# How to create javaFX application view

Tags: java, html, javafx

I am new to javaFX. I am starting an application in javaFX. I want to know that which is suitable to start an application.

My first screen is a form which has two fields(a select option field and a textfield autofill).
A button at bottom (onclick on button a popup form will open and How to open a popup in javafx).

Which is better for this.

- Create whole view in javaFX.
- Create in fxml file. or
- Create a html view and load this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go for fxml file because in this you can load css file also its easy too

This is a simple popup demo program

```
public class PopupTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        Button btn = new Button("Display Popup");
        btn.setOnMouseClicked(new PopupOpenEvent(stage));
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        stage.setTitle("Popup demo");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        //stage.setVisible(true);       
    }

    class PopupOpenEvent implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        private Stage stage;

        PopupOpenEvent(Stage s){
            stage = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            Popup popup = new Popup();

            HBox box = new HBox();
            box.getChildren().add(new Label("In popup..."));
            box.setPrefSize(100, 100);
            box.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray;");

            popup.getContent().add(box);          
            popup.setX(e.getScreenX());
            popup.setY(e.getScreenY());
            popup.show(stage);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to know that if I go for html(it is easy to create UI part) then what are the consequences and how could I handle the request form view.

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer I want to know one more thing please. How could open a popup on click on a button.

Comment: Atleast tell me the solution about popup please.

Comment: @SumitRaghav Sorry i did not see ,Here is the answer

Comment: @SumitRaghav delete unncessary comments because i think this comments will not be useful to future useful as it is not relevant to this question and answer